packaging Open3D as debian
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, CUDA 11.4, and I want to create a debian of Open3D 0.18.0, to do so I cloned the repo and tried:
mkdir build && cd build

cmake -DBUILD_CUDA_MODULE=ON -DBUILD_COMMON_CUDA_ARCHS=ON -DGLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=ON -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DUSE_SYSTEM_JPEG=ON -DCPACK_BINARY_DEB=ON ..

sudo make -j 10 package

but instead of getting a debian package (.deb) I got a different format (.tar.xz) with include, shared, lib folders:
open3d-devel-linux-x86_64-cxx11-abi-cuda-0.18.0+0f06a149c.tar.xz generated.

Can you please tell me how to create a debian please? thanks

Solution was to change this variable here to be:
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)

and to compile with make package
